# How to compile OpenZeppelin contracts using solc from command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, solidity, openzeppelin

Originally posted to OpenZeppelin forums, figured I'd post this here in case someone runs into this down the road and needs a little help.

Need the ABI and BIN for Rust web3 library (ick, I know). So far I've been using `solc --bin path/to/MyContract.sol` which has been working fine, until now that I've imported the `Initializeable.sol`. Semi-predictably, solc can't find this. I've tried passing in `--allow-paths "@openzeppelin == node_modules/openzeppelin"` and variations of, but solc still can't seem to find this. Does anyone know the correct usage for compiling my contract that imports an @openzeppelin contract in node_modules from the command line using solc?

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `--base-path '/'` and `--include-path 'node_modules/`'` flags.